# Orthogonal art gallery problem.

Tags: geometry, triangulation

Here is a problem:
One should position the least amount of cameras in an art gallery. The walls in the gallery are represented only by horizontal and vertical line segments.

I am trying to find the least amount of cameras possible at first. Given that the gallery is represented as a graph it seems that I should place n/4 cameras, where n is a number of vertices in the graph. And I am struggling around it.

What I know how to do is how to triangulate the gallery. I suspect it can help immensely.

So, how can I show that n/4 cameras at most are needed to cover such a gallery?

Comment: See [Art gallery problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem), which has the optimal solution $n/3$, although there the walls can meet at other angles than $90^\circ$.

Comment: @Arthur, I know the solution, thanks. Now, I would like to find one for the case described above.

Comment: Did you check out the paragraph called "[Generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem#Generalizations)" in that wikipedia article?

Comment: @Arthur, I know how to triangulate the polygon. I think that it will be easier for me to go from that instead of going from scratch.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant with my previous comment. Your orthogonal art gallery is mentioned specifically in the Wikipedia article. $n/4$ is indeed the solution, and the article links what looks like three separate proofs (note number 8), although it comments that none of them are simple.